# Slickgrid: What causes this extra column?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

In this example there's a dead leftmost column that I can't figure out how to suppress. Where in the code is this column created and how can I remove it?

http://labs.nereo.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-excel-compatible-spreadsheet.html

It's absent in the vanilla Slickgrid examples (e.g. http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html ) but I don't see the difference. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the column numbers. You can remove it by removing this part from the `columns` array:

Change this:

```
var columns = [
    {
      id: "selector",
      name: "",
      field: "num",
      width: 30
    }
  ];
```

To this:

```
var columns = [];
```